# How a 3D numpy array is tranposed

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transpose

I'm learning Numpy in this break :-D, and I today came across transpose. I can understand the transpose of a 2D matrix well, but had a hard time understanding the transpose of a 3D matrix (array). Can someone explain me how `a4` has been subjected to `.transpose()` in the following snippet? Sure I can find a pattern here, but I want to know the general principle behind transpose so that I will be able to apply it to a matrix of any dimension. Any help is highly appreciated.

```py
In [84]: a4 = np.random.randint(12,size=(3,2,3))
         a4
         array([[[ 2, 10,  8],
                 [ 1,  4,  9]],

                [[ 9, 10,  2],
                 [10,  5,  9]],

                [[ 0,  5,  2],
                 [ 6,  8,  2]]])

In [85]: a4.T
         array([[[ 2,  9,  0],
                 [ 1, 10,  6]],

                [[10, 10,  5],
                 [ 4,  5,  8]],

                [[ 8,  2,  2],
                 [ 9,  9,  2]]])
```

Comment: Replace random with a sequence of distinct elements, so you can map where transpose take them, and stare at it for a period of time, until the light turns on!

Comment: Look at `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`

Answer (score 2):

What helps me to think about transpose is to realize that the shape array gets flipped like a mirroring operation when transposed. See below:

```
a2 = np.random.randint(12,size=(3,2))
print('{} <=> {}'.format(a2.shape, a2.T.shape))

a3 = np.random.randint(12,size=(3,2,4))
print('{} <=> {}'.format(a3.shape, a3.T.shape))

a4 = np.random.randint(12,size=(3,2,4,5))
print('{} <=> {}'.format(a4.shape, a4.T.shape))
```

results in

```
(3, 2) <=> (2, 3)
(3, 2, 4) <=> (4, 2, 3)
(3, 2, 4, 5) <=> (5, 4, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Unless you specify a custom permutation through `a.transpose(...)`

Comment: Yeah I could find that pattern, but what I find difficult to understand is how one can write the transpose by looking at a4. Surely, I could determine the dimensions of the transposed matrix, but how do I determine the matrx content? Is there any general principle that allows me to write the transpose of any matrix?

Comment: More often I  am not concerned about the matrix content but concerned about how the contents get moved around when you transpose. This is because it is hard to visualize an array with more than 3 dimensions. I (and other I assume) use transposes and follow  them with some kind of matrix/array operation like multiplication, addition etc. Hope that helps.